# Click handlers for SVG polygons

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

How can I write this shorter?

```
$('#pietra_svg #p1_4 polygon#p1').click(function() {
  $('#apla_p1').fadeIn("slow");
  return false;
});
$('#pietra_svg #p1_4 polygon#p2').click(function() {
  $('#apla_p2').fadeIn("slow");
  return false;
});
$('#pietra_svg #p1_4 polygon#p3').click(function() {
  $('#apla_p3').fadeIn("slow");
  return false;
});
$('#pietra_svg #p1_4 polygon#p4').click(function() {
  $('#apla_p4').fadeIn("slow");
  return false;
});
$('#pietra_svg #p5 polygon#a').click(function() {
  $('#apla_p5').fadeIn("slow");
  return false;
});
$('#pietra_svg #p5 polygon#b').click(function() {
  $('#apla_p5').fadeIn("slow");
  return false;
});
$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.apla').fadeOut("slow");
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array in a similar way here. Just leave the last one, as it doesn't fit the same pattern.

```
$.each(
  [
    { poly: 'p1', id: '#apla_p1' },
    { poly: 'p2', id: '#apla_p2' },
    { poly: 'p3', id: '#apla_p3' },
    { poly: 'p4', id: '#apla_p4' },
    { poly: 'a', id: '#apla_p5' },
    { poly: 'b', id: '#apla_p5' }
  ],
  function(o){
    var id = o.id; // copy to closure
    $('#pietra_svg #p1_4 polygon#' + o.poly).click(function() {
      $(id).fadeIn("slow");
      return false;
    });
  }
);

$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.apla').fadeOut("slow");
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of id's you shouldn't use, if #p1 is unique (as it should), `$('#p1')` should be the same as `$('#pietra_svg #p1_4 polygon#p1')`. You should try to **review your svg tags**,

You can also **cache the root of the query**, saving a lot of time searching the dom:

```
var pietra = $('#pietra_svg')
```

and then

```
pietra.find('#p1_4 polygon#p1')
```

Also, for the first four elements you may **bind them once**, and with the clicked element id, find element to fade:

```
pietra.find('#p1_4 polygon').click(function() {
  $('#apla_' + this.id).fadeIn("slow");
  return false;
});
```